# Django: How to prefetch related object with model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
ClassA:
 ...

ClassB:
    ForeignKey(A)

ClassC：
    ForeignKey(B)
```

now I have a instance of C.

```
c = C()
b = c.b
a = b.a
```

This way, the db will be visited for three times.

How can I let them be fetched at once like prefetch_related.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

```
c = C.objects.select_related('b__a').get()
```

This will fetch both the b and a instances that were related to it.

Comment: Does not fetch only 'a'?

Comment: No, you have to traverse the relationships.